# How to call error() from within an async function in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, redirect, promise, svelte, sveltekit

When using `error()` from inside an `async` function, the script crashes with this error.

Using `import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';`

How can I call `error()` from within an `async` function in Svelte?

```
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "#<Redirect>".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}

Node.js v20.11.0
```

**Code Minimum Sample**
src/routes/+page.svelte (loading base URL)

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';

    const tst = async() => error( 400, 'My error message' );

    tst();
</script>
```

**Case 2** This code produces a smilar error (uncaught (in promise)) in the JS console

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    onMount( async function() 
    {
        error( 400, 'My error message' );
    } ); 
</script>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Removing async from the function does solves this issue, but I would like to use async please.

And I also would like to avoid having to use `try .. catch` around every async function call.

Comment: It would help if you posted some code.  In general you need to get that information that a redirect is required to the level where you would call a return.  I'll assume this is some exceptional behavior.  If you're `await`ing something you could, for example, throw an error and look for it in a `catch` block and then return a redirect based on that.

Comment: @possum Well, it's basically, `async function` inside `async` inside `async` inside `async`, through multiple files. Do I need to `throw` and `try - catch` that for every hierarchical call? (e.g. `try { await x(); } catch( e ) { redirect( .. ); async x() { try { await y(); } catch( e ) { throw new Error( 'error' ) }` etc?

Comment: @possum I added my code (abstract).

Comment: Where is `my_http_request` called? If you are on the page you are supposed to use `goto`, not `redirect`.

Comment: @brunnerh The first function is called in `+page-server.ts`

Comment: I think this should just work, show your code.

Comment: @brunnerh Code updated with a minimum reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error` is meant for server functions like `load` and returns the HTTP response with the respective status. If you get the error from some server-side function, you probably forgot to `await` some function.

You should generally not use/need `error` in client code.

On the client I would opt to show errors within the given page or show something like an error notification rather than showing an entire error page (which can be unnecessarily disruptive).

You could still show an error page by e.g. [setting up a context](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#setcontext) in a layout and conditionally show an error component rather than the slot containing the page. The context could contain a callback that can be invoked by a page on error.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how the context works. I tried setting a context with a specific key in my page and getting this context in the layout, but even if I change its value, the value in the layout is not updated and so the layout is not changed either. I would like to show an entire page error in case of server outage.

Comment: @Z0q: If you need reactivity, you have to put a store into the context. You can however also just pass in a function that closes over local state, then call that function in the page.